# Alternative way to configure IP address

Tags: ip, embedded, busybox

I am setting up an embedded linux device which should grab its IP-address and its MAC address at boot from files in the filesystem. Lets say there is a file `/root/ipaddress` with the only content "192.168.10.10" and `/root/macaddress` with "02:02:02:02:02:02" . The rest of the configuration should not be configurable.

Currently the the network configuration is done via `ifup -i /etc/interfaces -a`, where the IP-address is defined in the stanza:

```
# The loopback network interface
#auto lo
#iface eth0 inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0

iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.10.10
    netmask 255.255.255.0
```

I have tried to use environment variables in the /etc/interfaces file without success.

I could build a script using `ip` commands where I would bring down the interface again, configure IP and MAC address, and bring it up again. However that seems quite inefficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ifupdown` set of scripts isn't designed to work that way.

Instead, you may:

1. Stop using `ifupdown` and manage to configure the networking by yourself inside a dedicated script. (i would probably choose this option)
2. Use the `post-up` feature of `ifupdown`, that way:

```
iface eth0 inet static
  pre-up ifconfig eth0 hw ether `cat /root/macaddress`
  address 0.0.0.0
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  post-up ifconfig eth0 `cat /root/ipaddress`
```

Note that i didn't tested if post-up is able to manage the backtick construct. ..

Maybe you can also dig around the `manual` methods (instead of `static`) ...

Comment: Thanks! While I was waiting for an answer I came to a similar conclusion. The `post-up` works for configuring the IP-address! While for configuring the MAC address `pre-up` is necessary. Because when the interface is up the MAC address can't be changed, i guess.

Comment: You're right regarding the HW address: interface must be down to be able to do this. Answer corrected!